# Question about scanf function in C

Tags: c

I've got a question about how the scanf function works. In this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int x;
    char y;

    printf("Write a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    printf("Write a character: ");
    scanf(" %c", &y);

    printf("%d", x);
    printf("%c", y);

    return 0;
}
```

If the user writes a number then hit enter then the scanf function would see from the format string that is should expect a number. When the user taps enter it would not read the new-line character and put it back in the buffer. Then since I am reading a character next I need to have a whitespace in the format string because the scanf function would otherwise take the new-line character and put in the y-variable.

However I am just curious about what happened if the user wrote something like

> j344lk4fjk388

Would it put everything back in the buffer? And everything that gets "put-back" in the buffer would it automatically be read by the next scanf function in my program?

> I'm reading: [C Programming A Modern Approach 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393979504)

Comment: Why not compile the program and just feed it that input to find out? Add logging statements or use a debugger if you need to see something going on that isn't already visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should always check the return value from `scanf()` to ensure that all the conversions you expected were successful.

Given the sample input:

```
j344lk4fjk388
```

The first `scanf()` would fail because `j` cannot be converted to an integer - returning 0 for the number of successful conversions.  The second call would succeed, returning 'j' as the character.

If you need the string to be treated as an integer, use `fgets()` or a relative (perhaps POSIX `getline()`) to read the string, then `strtoul()` (or the appropriate relative - `strtol()`, `strtoll()`, `strtoull()`, `strtoimax()` or `strtoumax()`), specifying a base of at least 21 to convert the 'j', or 23 to take the 'l' and 'k'.

Answer (score 1):

> Error handling
>
> scanf is usually used in situations
>   when the program cannot guarantee that
>   the input is in the expected format.
>   Therefore a robust program must check
>   whether the scanf call succeeded and
>   take appropriate action. If the input
>   was not in the correct format, the
>   erroneous data will still be on the
>   input stream and must be read and
>   discarded before new input can be
>   read. An alternative method of reading
>   input, which avoids this, is to use
>   fgets and then examine the string read
>   in. The last step can be done by
>   sscanf, for example.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf

Answer (score 0):

It will put everything that was not matched by scanf back in the buffer. Eg: `scanf("%i %i",...)` given the input "`12 qwe`" will leave `qwe` in the buffer but not `12`. (The [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fscanf.html) suggests it won't put the space back, and a quick test confirms.) That said, the documentation is rather unclear, and it is probably a bad idea to rely on it without doing plenty of tests.

Comment: Strictly, it will leave the `q` as the next character to be read - it won't even see the `w` let alone the `e`.  The `scanf()` will return 1 (for one successful conversion).  The space will not be put back; it was successfully matched by the space in the format string.

Comment: @Jonathan But for clarity, if the format string were `"%i%i"`, the space would be put back, correct?

Comment: @Null Set: I think that even if the format string contained no space, then the space would still not be put back because `scanf()` uses at most one character of push back, and the space was a valid start to the second number; the character pushed back is the one that caused the conversion to fail, and that's the '`q`' in this example.  I suppose I should write the test to prove the point - but I'm feeling too lazy, and it would only show that at least one implementation had (or did not have) that behaviour, not that the standard mandates that behaviour.

Comment: @Null Set, test suggests it won't even then.

Comment: @Jonathan After reading the spec a bit more, I believe that it will not put the space back. It first skips whitespaces, then looks for a matching input and leaves the first non-matching character unread.

Comment: @Null Set: §7.19.6.2 of C99, ¶8 says "[i]nput white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier", so the space is skipped and not pushed back ('left unread' is the term used in the standard).